# Function that accepts factor and numerical inputs

Tags: r, function, select, optimization, dplyr

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to optimize a function that can accept numerical and factor inputs.

For the optimization, I use [GA](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GA) library.
My references: [demo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html), [actual Library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/index.html), [specific function I'm using](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GA/versions/3.2.1/topics/ga)

Suppose I have a function that looks like this:

```r
my_function <- function(r1, r2) {
    #define function here, e.g:

    #this "select" can be done using "dplyr" or SQL part1 <- SELECT * FROM
    my_data WHERE (col_1 IN r1) AND (col_2 > r2)

    part2<- mean(part1$col_3)
}
```

In this example:

- `r1` can take any `group` of values of `a, b, c, d` (factor variable),
  e.g. `r1 = a`, `r1 = a,d`, `r1 = b,c,a`, `r1 = c`, `r1 = a,b,c,d` etc.
- `r2` can take a single value between 1 and 100 (numeric variable)
- `my_data` is a dataset that has 3 columns: `col_1` (factor, can only take values `a, b, c, d`), `col_2` (numeric), `col_3` (numeric)
- `my_data` will be "subsetted" according to `r1` and `r2`
- the `mean` of `col_3` is the value that `my_function` will return given a choice of `r1` and `r2`
- the `mean` of `col_3` will be the value that I am trying to optimize for a choice of `r1` and `r2`

**Problem:** Currently, I am trying to optimize `my_function` using the `ga` function in R:

```
library(GA)
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = function(x)  my_function(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 1), upper = c(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 100), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)
```

But I am not sure how to set this up correctly.
I am not sure how to correctly define `my_function` and I am not sure how to correctly define GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```r
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(a = rep(letters[1:3], each=2),
                 b = rep(c(1,9), 3),
                 c = 1:6)
df
#>   a b c
#> 1 a 1 1
#> 2 a 9 2
#> 3 b 1 3
#> 4 b 9 4
#> 5 c 1 5
#> 6 c 9 6

my_subset_mean <- function(r1, r2){ ## Assumes an object `df` with cols a|b|c
  subset <- df %>% filter(a %in% r1, b > r2)
  return(mean(subset$c))
}

my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a"), r2 = 5) ## ~mean(2)
#> [1] 2
my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 0) ## ~mean(1:4)
#> [1] 2.5
my_subset_mean(r1 = c("a", "b"), r2 = 10) ## ~mean of df with 0 rows
#> [1] NaN
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: @ R_Pseudo: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you know if this function you have created "my_subset_mean" : will the "ga" algorithm in R accept "my_subset_mean"? Thanks!